# How to update CodeBlocks in Kali Linux?

Tags: terminal, upgrade, kali-linux, application, programming

I installed CodeBlocks on Kali Linux but I got 10.05 version and I want to update it to 13.12, preferably via terminal.

Also I would like to know how to update any application this way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to download the deb package and open it up using the file explorer. Then it is possible it will install.

You can download the .deb on the official Debian site at https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages then use

```
dpkg -i package.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal you would use `apt-get` to upgrade the package. You would want to try:

`sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade <packagename>`

Comment: I tried it and it tells me that Codeblocks is already the newest version...

Comment: The next question would be if Kali Linux would support CodeBlocks 13.12, it may specifically be available for certain distros. Just so you aware, Kali Linux is used for penetration testing.. That may be the reason why 10.05 is the newest update for that distro

Comment: Yeah,I suppose Kali doesn't support Codeblocks 13.12,but there really isn't any way to update it?

Comment: I would check with CodeBlocks and see for certain if 13.12 is unsupported on Kali Linux